# Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':google_mobile_ads' of type org.gradle.api.Project

Tags: flutter, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Flutter version : 3.7
Andriod Studio : Dolphin | 2022.1. 1

i have updated the gradle several times but nothing change and also upgraded the JDK to 17

before:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4-all.zip

after:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.1'

distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-all.zip

nothing different.

any suggestions?

---